# Rails 5 update date using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have `Contract` model with an `accept_date` attribute

I want to update the `accept_date` via `link_to` using a custom method which can also change its AASM state. Is it better to do it by passing the params from the view as `link_to` `put` or by doing it in the controller as `link_to` `get`?

#### view

```
// put
= link_to 'Accept', custom_method(@contract, contract: {accept_date: Time.now}), method: :put
// get
= link_to 'Accept', custom_method(@contract)
```

#### controller

```
def custom_method
 @contract.aasm_accept!
 @contract.update(contract_params) # if put
 @contract.update_attributes(accept_date: Time.now) # if get
```

Also, what is the difference between `Time.now` and `Date.today` and other helpers to get the current time and are they dependent on `t.date` `t.time` and `t.datetime`? Can I use `Date.today` for a `t.time` attribute?

I used the methods above and the database shows a commit, but nothing is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly add method after updating state like below, so need to write in the method of the controller, use PUT instead of GET because you are updating something

your_model.rb

```
event :aasm_accept do
  transitions from: :nothing, to: :everything, after: proc { |*_args| update_date_value }
end


def update_date_value
 # your business logic
end
```

The difference of .current and .now is .now use the server's timezone, while .current use what the Rails environment is set to. If it's not set, then .current will be same as .now.

Date.today will give you today's date without timezone.
Time.current will give you current time with time zones configured in rails application.